# painting area dynamic lines plot

Tags: matlab, plot

in matlab you can color the area between two lines printed on a plot. 
The following code prints a dynamic plot.

```
figure('doublebuffer','on')
t=0;
r=32;
g=32
axes('xlim',[0 24], ...
    'nextplot','add') 
p1=plot(t,r,'r','LineWidth',2);
p2=plot(t,r,'b.','MarkerSize',15);
p3=plot(t,g,'b','LineWidth',2);
p4=plot(t,g,'g.','MarkerSize',15);
for t=1:24
ylim('auto')
r=abs(22*(rand(1,1)+1));
g=abs(8*(rand(1,1)+1))
set(p1,'xdata',[get(p1,'xdata') t],...
    'ydata',[get(p1,'ydata') r]) 
set(p2,'xdata',t,...
    'ydata',r)
set(p3,'xdata',[get(p3,'xdata') t],...
    'ydata',[get(p3,'ydata') g]) 
set(p4,'xdata',t,...
    'ydata',g)
pause(0.5) 
end
```

What I was wondering if you could color the area between the two lines that are dinamically plot (now is white color but I wonder if you can change the color of an area)
I would put a sample but I have enough points.Also I was wondering if you could smooth out the spikes in the graph when there are wide variations.

Thanks in advance for the help. I hope I was clear in explaining. I tried to use the command **area()** but with no success ....

Answer (score 1):

With regard to filling with a color between two lines, you can use the function [FILL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fill.html). Here's a modification of your example showing how you can do it:

```
t = 0:24;                %# t values
r = [32 zeros(1,24)];    %# Initialize r values
g = [32 zeros(1,24)];    %# Initialize g values
hFill = fill([t(1) t(1)],[r(1) g(1)],'r');  %# Fill between r and g with red
for iPoint = 2:length(t)
  r(iPoint) = 22*(rand+1);  %# Add a value to r
  g(iPoint) = 8*(rand+1);   %# Add a value to g
  set(hFill,'XData',[t(1:iPoint) t(iPoint:-1:1)],...  %# Update x data
            'YData',[r(1:iPoint) g(iPoint:-1:1)]);    %# Update y data
  pause(0.5);
end
```

You can then add in your plotting of the leading points for the traces.

Comment: thanks a lot, I saw the command fill but I was not able to make it effective in the loop. We are grateful for the help